# Optimizing timedelta calculation between two dates with different 'weekmask' logic in Polars

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, python-polars

I am very impressed of the Polars library and trying to learn it better. :)

Now I am trying to calculate days between two dates in Polars for millions of rows, but there are conditions that for some rows I need to exclude certain weekdays. In Pandas/Numpy I have utilized np.busday_count where I can define a weekmask of which weekdays to count per condition and also exclude holidays when needed.

I'm having difficulties counting the days with conditions in a fast way as I can't figure the way how to do this in expression.

Example dataframe:

```
df = (pl
    .DataFrame({"Market": ["AT", "DE", "AT", "CZ", "GB", "CZ"],
              "Service": ["Standard", "Express", "Standard", "Standard", "Standard", "Standard"],
              "Day1": ["2022-01-02","2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-07"],
              "Day2": ["2022-01-03","2022-01-04", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-07", "2022-01-08"]
             }
            )
    .with_columns(pl.col(["Day1", "Day2"]).str.strptime(pl.Date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
)
```

I was able to pass the data to np.busday_function through struct and apply method. However the execution is much slower with the real dataset (34.4 seconds) compared to Pandas assign (262ms).

Below the code I was able to come up with in Polars. I'm looking for an optimized way of doing this quicker.

```
(df
    .with_column(
        pl.struct([pl.col("Day1"), pl.col("Day2")])
        .apply(lambda x: np.busday_count(x["Day1"], x["Day2"], weekmask='1110000'))
        .alias("Result"))
)
```

EDIT, expected output:

```
┌────────┬──────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────┐
│ Market ┆ Service  ┆ Day1       ┆ Day2       ┆ Result │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---    │
│ str    ┆ str      ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64    │
╞════════╪══════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════╡
│ AT     ┆ Standard ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ DE     ┆ Express  ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ AT     ┆ Standard ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 2022-01-05 ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ CZ     ┆ Standard ┆ 2022-01-05 ┆ 2022-01-06 ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ GB     ┆ Standard ┆ 2022-01-06 ┆ 2022-01-07 ┆ 0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ CZ     ┆ Standard ┆ 2022-01-07 ┆ 2022-01-08 ┆ 0      │
└────────┴──────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `apply` in the `select` context, you will be creating a python dictionary and feeding that to your lambda for every element in the list. This is expensive.

You can utilize `vectorization`, by using `map` instead of apply. That way we can send whole columns at a time to numpys `busday_count`.

```py
(df
    .with_column(
        pl.struct([pl.col("Day1"), pl.col("Day2")])
        .map(lambda x: np.busday_count(x.struct["Day1"], x.struct["Day2"], weekmask='1110000'))
        .alias("Result"))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can now do this within Polars, but you'll need the [polars-xdt](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars-xdt) plugin

```py
import polars_xdt as xdt

df.with_columns(
    result = xdt.workday_count(
        'Day1',
        'Day2',
        weekend=['Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    )
)
```

output:

```
Out[6]:
shape: (6, 5)
┌────────┬──────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────┐
│ Market ┆ Service  ┆ Day1       ┆ Day2       ┆ result │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---    │
│ str    ┆ str      ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i32    │
╞════════╪══════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════╡
│ AT     ┆ Standard ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 0      │
│ DE     ┆ Express  ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 1      │
│ AT     ┆ Standard ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 2022-01-05 ┆ 1      │
│ CZ     ┆ Standard ┆ 2022-01-05 ┆ 2022-01-06 ┆ 1      │
│ GB     ┆ Standard ┆ 2022-01-06 ┆ 2022-01-07 ┆ 0      │
│ CZ     ┆ Standard ┆ 2022-01-07 ┆ 2022-01-08 ┆ 0      │
└────────┴──────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────┘
```

This is orders of magnitude faster than using `map_elements` (formerly `apply`), and works with Polars lazy mode